# Thread throwing object not found but object is clearly there

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, nullreferenceexception

I have an application in C# VS11 Beta.

The code below throws `NullReferenceException` (commented line)

```cs
private void ParralelProcessor(Int32 threadNum)
{
    HashSet<Feature> Features = new HashSet<Feature>();
    HashSet<FeatureType> FeatureTypes = new  HashSet<FeatureType>();
    DataTable TopographicFeatures = new DataTable();
    DataTable TopographicFeatureObjects = new DataTable();
    DataTable CartographicText = new DataTable();
    DataTable CartographicSymbol = new DataTable();
    List<DataRow> FeaturesAsRows = new List<DataRow>();
    List<DataRow> FeatureObjectsAsRows = new List<DataRow>();
    List<DataRow> CartographicTextAsRows = new List<DataRow>();
    List<DataRow> CartographicSymbolAsRows = new List<DataRow>();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    TopographicFeatures.Columns.Add("fid", typeof(System.Int64));
    TopographicFeatures.Columns.Add("FeatureId", typeof(System.Int16));
    TopographicFeatureObjects.Columns.Add("fid", typeof(System.Int64));
//BELOW
    TopographicFeatureObjects.Columns.Add("GeoCoordinates", typeof(SqlGeometry)); //THIS LINE
//ABOVE
    TopographicFeatureObjects.Columns.Add("TypeId", typeof(System.Int16));
    CartographicText.Columns.Add("fid", typeof(System.Int64));
    CartographicText.Columns.Add("textString", typeof(System.String));
    CartographicText.Columns.Add("anchorPosition", typeof(System.Int16));
    CartographicText.Columns.Add("font", typeof(System.Int16));
    CartographicText.Columns.Add("height", typeof(System.Decimal));
    CartographicText.Columns.Add("orientation", typeof(System.Decimal));
    CartographicSymbol.Columns.Add("fid", typeof(System.Int64));
    CartographicSymbol.Columns.Add("orientation", typeof(System.Decimal));
```

The debug information shows that the table is not `null` and neither is the column collection.

It is run inside a method that is called in a `Parralel.For` loop as below

```cs
Parallel.For(1, ThreadsPerFile + 1, X => { ParralelProcessor(X); });
```

All objects are declared and disposed in the method therefore each thread has its own instance.

I'm a bit stumped as to why this is throwing an exception.

Comment: Can you include the full error text and call stack?

Comment: Does it work in a normal for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

Does the code run fine when the line is commented out?
I have a feeling the issue is either not on that line, or it's the SqlGeometry that's throwing things off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with this kind of column, but maybe this will help a bit:

Since SqlGeometry is not one of the base types in .NET, make sure you adhere to this quote from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Although it is possible to define a column as data type other than the
>   base .NET Framework data types and Byte[], such a column will be
>   treated as a user-defined type, subject to the following usage
>   restrictions. (For more information on user-defined types, see
>   Creating and Using User-Defined Types.)
>
> The column cannot be part of a RowFilter or Select expression.
>
> If the column is used as a PrimaryKey, or as a Sort or for a DataView,
>   it must be treated as an immutable field; the column data must not be
>   changed once it has been added to the table.
>
> Its ColumnMapping can be only set to MappingType.Element.
>
> The class that implements the column’s data type must be must be
>   marked with the SerializableAttribute, and if necessary implement the
>   ISerializable or IXmlSerializable interface.
>
> Support for change tracking is limited. To utilize the DataTable
>   class’s change tracking mechanism, the class that implements the
>   column’s data type must either implement the IChangeTracking
>   interface, or take over the responsibility for informing the DataRow
>   when the column value has been modified, either by calling SetModified
>   on the row or by assigning the column value object to a separately
>   instantiated column value object.

Good Luck!